# Haproxy frontend authorization

Tags: haproxy

I am new to haproxy.

I create a `frontend` named `crawler`, and bind port 3000. Here are my frontend configuration:

```
frontend crawler
    bind               *:3000
    mode               http
    log                global
    default_backend    crawler-proxy
    option             httplog
    option             http_proxy
```

Now, I can access the frontend like:

`curl -v --proxy 'http://127.0.0.1:3000' httpbin.org/ip`

But, I want to do that with username and password, like:

`curl -v --proxy 'http://username:password@127.0.0.1:3000' httpbin.org/ip`

Can anyone tell me how to configurate `/etc/haproxy/haproxy.cfg`?

Thanks very much!

Comment: You have to handle the authentication at the app itself.

Comment: @Ianthe Do you mean that i have to handle the authentication at the backend?

Comment: Yes. But looking around, there's seems to be a way to do it at the proxy level. Check this out: http://serverfault.com/a/242936/101643 This is basic auth and the passwords are maintained within the `haproxy.cfg` file. I won't recommend this though.

Comment: @Ianthe I see. Thanks.